# array is added to email address

Tags: php, arrays, email

i was using this codes to send newsletter to members , now the problem is that when i send emails it doesn't send . i tracked the emails in cpanel and found that the email address has the word 'array' before it . that means that when i send to 'email@domain.com' it changes to 'arrayemail@domain.com'. and this is the code :

```
<?php
include("../include/config.php");
include_once("../include/functions/import.php");
verify_login_admin();
$adminurl = $config['adminurl'];
$thebaseurl = $config['baseurl'];

$sql = "SELECT USERID, username, email FROM members";
$executequery = $conn->Execute($sql);
$results= $executequery->getrows();

if($_POST['submitform'] == "1")
{
if(isset($_POST['USERID']))
    {   
foreach($_POST['USERID'] as $key) 
    {
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $sendername = $config['site_name'];
    //$bodymessage = "Dear " . $_POST['username'];
    //$sendmailbody = "HI". $results[$i]. $key . $results[$i].$_POST['username'] .",";
    $sendmailbody .= $_POST['message'];
    $sendmailbody .= "";
            $from = $config['site_name'].'<'.$config['site_email'].'>';
    $sendto = $results[$i]. $key.',';
    mailme($sendto,$sendername,$from,$subject,$sendmailbody,$bcc);
    }
    }
    $message = "E-Mails / Newsletters sent successfully.";
    Stemplate::assign('message',$message);
}


$mainmenu = "7";
$submenu = "2";
$bodymsg = $_POST['message'];
Stemplate::assign('subject',$subject);
Stemplate::assign('bodymsg',$bodymsg);
Stemplate::assign('mainmenu',$mainmenu);
Stemplate::assign('submenu',$submenu);
Stemplate::assign('results',$results);
STemplate::display("administrator/global_header.tpl");
STemplate::display("administrator/mass_newsletter.tpl");
STemplate::display("administrator/global_footer.tpl");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting all rows from your query:

```
$results= $executequery->getrows();
                               ^ plural
```

But you never actually loop over all rows, so `$results[$i]` will contain one complete row from the result set: An array containing the USERID, username and email.

And when you concatenate an array with a string, the array will result in the text `array`.

And that is assuming that `$i` is an integer but in your code it is not defined at all.

You probably want to loop over the result-set somewhere and if you use a `foreach` you will not need the `$i` variable at all:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    // Build your e-mail addresses string?
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , i am using tpl file to choose members email address and it has a section loop

`{section name=i loop=$results}
 <input type='checkbox' name='USERID[{$results[i].USERID}]' id="USERID[{$results[i].USERID}]"  value="{$results[i].email}">
{$results[i].email} | {$results[i].username}<br />
{/section}`

Comment: and by the way , it was working fine with me until few days ago